# Catenary Equation for golden gate bridge

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, physics

I have no knowledge at all about catenary equations, I am only required to know the simple math. I am doing it for the main suspension cable of the golden gate bridge.

The equation for a catenary is $y=​\frac12 ​a\left(e^{​ax}+e​^{−ax}\right)$, and the points are $(0,0), (640, 152),$ and $(-640,152)$. The website http://www.intmath.com/applications-integration/11-arc-length-curve.php used a "guess and check" method and got the equation $$y=1280\left(\frac{e^{x/1326} + e^{-x/1326}}{2} -1\right).$$

I plugged in $x=640$, $y=152$ and tried to solve for $a$, but it is not working. Is there a specific way to solve it?? 
Plzzz help this is for my math is...
if there is no way, is there any way to form a catenaric equation without working with tension, force, and physics in general.

Comment: It looks like they've modified the catenary a bit in order to make it go through the required points. The first modification is that they subtract a constant from the catenary in order to make it go through $(0,0)$; that's not a bit deal, since it just shifts the catenary down a bit. What I don't see is why two constants 1326, 1280 show up when only one constant ($a$) appears in the catenary equation. (It's also worth noting that they misstate the form of the catenary: it should have $e^{x/a}$, not $e^{ax}$. So I'd chalk it up to carelessness on their part.)

Comment: Also: There is a catenary equation with just one constant, and that's $y=a\left(\dfrac{e^{x/a}+e^{-x/a}}{2}-1\right)$ with $a=1371.98\approx 1372$ (found numerically with Mathematica). So I find their result to be pretty inscrutable.